# MYSQL select rows whose values are positive across all the x

Tags: mysql

I would like to perform a select similar to the example below. Basically I have three columns name, x, value. I would like to return the name whose values are all positive across a given range of x.

for example, I want to return the names whose values are all positive for x between 1 and 3, this should return y3 and y4. could anyone please help me, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Great. Now try something

Comment: And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You know how to select users with negative values, so basically you just want all users not in that result

Comment: @FlashThunder, I tried to use (where x between x1 and x2) and value >0, this returns everytime when value is positive. sorry if the question is very basic, I am very new to MYSQL, will read the doc more in details

Comment: @Strawberry, thanks, I will probably do more research before asking next time

Comment: Probably? How disappointing :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name
from your_table
where x between 1 and 3
group by name
having min(value) >= 0
```